# Excel: Need to Generate IDs based on multiple criteria with repeating IDs

Tags: arrays, excel

Looking to create pricing groups bases on multiple criteria. Each group could have multiple items within the group. I'm struggling with the autocreation the naming of each group. I estimate there should be about 6.5K pricing groups out of 14K items.

Below is the criteria -

QTY per case - is the number of bottles in a case
Size - size of the bottle
Family Brand - contains a group of like items
Code - CS1 - This is my unique code for each group that contains each of the above and lowest possible case price.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFw6B.png)

The "Thinking" column is how I want each group to look, but how do I do this with 14K items quickly?

Comment: is it allowed to sort the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your pricing group name consists of two parts: a simple combination of columns and a "special" column, that should be counted.
Part 1 is simple: `=C2&"-"&B2&"-"&A1&"-"`
To make Part 2 easier you could sort, sorting fields Part 1, CODE-CS1.

After have done this you could use helping columns. If Part 1 is in column x and code-CS1 in column y you could find a formula for
Part 2 (column z): `="T"&IF(X1=X2;IF(Y1=Y2;Z1;Z1+1);1)`

That means: If Part 1 is changing your counter starts with T1, if not so if your CODE CS1 changes, it counts, if not, so it keeps last number.

the result code would be `=X2&Z2`

It is untested and I use german excel, maybe the code doesn't work without any adaption, but in general it should work

Comment: It's finding the repeating values, but not returning T2 and so on.

Comment: And yes the data can be sorted.

Comment: Used this =IF(P2=P3,IF(M2=M3,1,R2+1),1) and got the below results. Still not what I'm looking for, but it does work for some.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Are you only missing the "T"? If so, then pay attention on ="T"& in the formula. If there is still another problem, so I did not understand completely. Please specify the rest problem

Comment: Why didn't you use =IF(P2=P3,IF(M2=M3,R1,R2+1),1)? Your formula should produce many "1" at the wrong places, isn't it?

Comment: That's what i went with - =IF(P2=P3,IF(M2=M3,R1,R2+1),1)